# How to send FormData and handle it at server-side using ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, html

Below is an Ajax request to a static web method at server. I want to send the file and its associated details to the server. Even if I send the data to the server, i'm not able to access the file at the server side using c#.net.

The most difficult part being accessing the FileUpload control in the static WebMethod.

```
$.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                url: 'UserProfile.aspx/EditProfile',
                                data: "{'file':'" + document.getElementById('FileUpload1').files[0] + "'}",
                                async: true,
                                success: function (response) {
                                    $('#dialog-form').dialog("close");
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: I want to use `FileUpload1` control in a `static WebMethod` but the scope of `FileUpload` control is not working within the static method. Plz help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't attempt to send the data as JSON, send it as formdata with [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) and you can read the file on the server side as if you used a regular form to upload the file.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', document.getElementById('FileUpload1').files[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'UserProfile.aspx/EditProfile',
    data: data,
    async: true,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (response) {
        $('#dialog-form').dialog("close");
    }
});
```